# Time complexity using Big-O notation

Tags: c#, algorithm, big-o, time-complexity, square-root

I am having trouble understanding this time complexity `O(sqrt(B))` given that `B` is an integer.

For example if I have a function...

```
int GetResult(int A, int B)
{
}
```

...and this function has a time complexity of `O(sqrt(B))`, what exactly is the time complexity?

Sorry if this is a little vague...I'm not really sure how else to explain.

Comment: It may mean that a counter will loop till sqrt(B). For instance if you want to know whether B is a prime number, then you just have to check for possible factors up to Sqrt(B).

Comment: Basically it means that if you made a graph of the time required to run the function as B increases, then over the long run, that graph would closely resemble the graph of the square root of B. To be more technical, it means that there is a constant C such that there comes a point eventually where the line of the first graph is always *under* the line of the graph of `C * sqrt(B)`. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 5):

The time complexity is an indicator of the runtime of a function relative to the amount of its input data.

given n data items for a function,

- O(n) means a function will simply pass over each data item "once". So doubling the input amout will double its duration.
- O(n<sup>2</sup>) would mean that a function for example has two nested loops over the data, so double the input amount and wait 4 times as long.
- O(log n) for example would only need logarithmic time, e.g. when you give 10 times more input, the function will only take one "step" longer.
- O(sqrt(n)) thus means when you give 4 times the input of a call, the function will only take twice the time.

The Big-O-Notation only states how a function scales, but not how long it actually takes. For instance, the Big-O-Notation ignores constant factors. e.g. A function that iterates 4 times over some data (4x loop in sequence) has O(4n), and that is equal to O(n).

This fact also shows why O(log<sub>10</sub> n) is equal to O(log<sub>2</sub> n):
log<sub>10</sub> n = (log<sub>2</sub> n) / (log<sub>2</sub> 10). As (log<sub>2</sub> 10) is a constant factor, it can be omited in Big-O-Notation. Thus you can choose whatever log you like, it will not mean any difference concerning Big-O-complexity.

When you have two inputs, say lists A and B, you use two variables for there size, say n resp. m.
A function that has complexity O(n^2 * log m) behaves as follows:

- doubling list A will result in much slower execution (i.e. 4x duration) but
- doubling list B will only result in only "one more iteration" over the A's processing duration of O(n<sup>2</sup>) (i.e. it will only take n^2 * (any unknown constant factor) longer.)

Comment: Your first explanation of O(log n) is incorrect; the second one is correct.

Comment: I love how this answer explains Big O without once mentioning the OP's O(sqrt(B)).

Comment: @Eric, Geobits: I hope, I fixed both. If not, please feel free, to edit and help me refresh my rusty knowledge of Big-O-Mechanics ;)

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question depends on B. 
If B = O(n^4), then O(sqrt(B)) = O(n^2)  
If B = O(n^2), then O(sqrt(B)) = O(n) 
If B = O(n), then O(sqrt(B)) = O(n^(1/2))